# using "specialized" in a sentence

Tags: grammar, american-english

I am a bit confused about how to use the word "**specialized**" in a sentence as in the following sentences:

1. The courses he took in medical school, made him **specialize** in medicine.
2. The courses he took in medical school, helped him to be **specialized** in medicine.

which one is correct? Or please suggest a better option.....

Please help....

Comment: In both examples, the commas should be removed.

Comment: You study medicine, and specialize in a branch of medicine.

Answer (score 3):

In a medical context, you wouldn't normally talk about being "specialized in medicine". You'd be specialized in a specific branch of medicine such as oncology or paediatrics.

With regard to "specialize in" versus "be specialized in", both are fine but your second example comes across somewhat unnaturally. You might also consider "become specialized in".

Comment: A medical student or doctor might "specialize within medicine" meaning choosing a sub-field of medicine, but "specialized in medicine" suggests choosing medicine as opposed to law, history, etc.

Comment: In a raw Google search, the ratio of hits for "specialized in" to "is specialised in" is about 1000 : 6.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentences do not mean the same thing and so whether they are correct or not depends on what meaning you wish to convey:

> 1. The courses he took in medical school, made him specialize in medicine.

means that those courses ***determined him to study medicine in a more specialized way***, (maybe choosing a particular branch as suggested by the previous answer). See *[to make somebody do something](https://www.gymglish.com/en/gymglish/english-grammar/to-make-somebody-do-something#:%7E:text=To%20make%20%2B%20object%20%2B%20verb%20in,to%20think%20of%20my%20boyfriend.)*

> 2. The courses he took in medical school, helped him to be/become specialized in medicine.

means that ***the result of those courses is that now he is specialized***. See *[to help somebody (to) do something](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/help_1)*